# Apache HttpClient Read timed out after a while

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-httpclient-4.x

I've scenario where I use Spring Boot + RestTemplate + Apache HttpClient to fetch information. In my current set-up I'm running the requests in 5 threads. But after few minutes, the connections start to time out.

When I restart the the Spring Boot app, the requests are fine again for a few minutes. Not sure what causes these timeouts.

```
2020-03-21 12:52:24.195 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache   : Auth cache not set in the context
2020-03-21 12:52:24.195 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection request: [route: {s}->https://www.somewebsite.com:443][total available: 5; route allocated: 1 of 20; total allocated: 5 of 20]
2020-03-21 12:52:24.195 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection leased: [id: 29][route: {s}->https://www.somewebsite.com:443][total available: 4; route allocated: 1 of 20; total allocated: 5 of 20]
2020-03-21 12:52:24.195 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection : http-outgoing-29: set socket timeout to 0
2020-03-21 12:52:24.195 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection : http-outgoing-29: set socket timeout to 10000
2020-03-21 12:52:24.195 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Executing request GET <url> HTTP/1.1
2020-03-21 12:52:24.195 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2020-03-21 12:52:24.195 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2020-03-21 12:52:24.195 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-29 >> GET <url> HTTP/1.1
2020-03-21 12:52:24.195 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-29 >> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
2020-03-21 12:52:24.195 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-29 >> Accept: text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*
2020-03-21 12:52:24.195 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-29 >> Host: www.somewebsite.com
2020-03-21 12:52:24.195 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-29 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2020-03-21 12:52:24.195 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-29 >> Cookie: <Cookies>
2020-03-21 12:52:24.196 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] org.apache.http.headers                  : http-outgoing-29 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
2020-03-21 12:52:24.196 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-29 >> "GET <url> HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2020-03-21 12:52:24.196 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-29 >> "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0[\r][\n]"
2020-03-21 12:52:24.196 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-29 >> "Accept: text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*[\r][\n]"
2020-03-21 12:52:24.196 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-29 >> "Host: www.somewebsite.com[\r][\n]"
2020-03-21 12:52:24.196 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-29 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2020-03-21 12:52:24.196 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-29 >> "Cookie: <cookies> [\r][\n]"
2020-03-21 12:52:24.196 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-29 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
2020-03-21 12:52:24.196 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-29 >> "[\r][\n]"
2020-03-21 12:52:34.197 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] org.apache.http.wire                     : http-outgoing-29 << "[read] I/O error: Read timed out"
2020-03-21 12:52:34.198 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection : http-outgoing-29: Close connection
2020-03-21 12:52:34.199 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection : http-outgoing-29: Shutdown connection
2020-03-21 12:52:34.199 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] o.a.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec   : Connection discarded
2020-03-21 12:52:34.199 DEBUG 72712 --- [        task-14] h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager : Connection released: [id: 29][route: {s}->https://www.somewebsite.com:443][total available: 4; route allocated: 0 of 20; total allocated: 4 of 20]
```

This is my setup

```
  @Bean
    public ClientHttpRequestFactory createRequestFactory(final CookieStore cookieStore) {
        final PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(20);
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);
        final RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig
                .custom()
                .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD)
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(5000)
                .setSocketTimeout(10000)
                .build();

        final CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients
                .custom()
                .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
                .build();
        return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(final ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory) {
        final DefaultUriBuilderFactory uriBuilderFactory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory(
                "<url>");
        uriBuilderFactory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.NONE);

        final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder()
                .uriTemplateHandler(uriBuilderFactory)
                .defaultHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0")
                .build(RestTemplate.class);

        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(clientHttpRequestFactory);
        return restTemplate;
    }
```

Even without reusing connections

```
HttpClients
                .custom()
                .setConnectionReuseStrategy(new NoConnectionReuseStrategy())...
```

I still encounter the problem. Maybe someone has encountered something similar or have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so that was nothing related to HttpClient. Apparently the server timed out requests, and was tracking client by cookie.